# How to activate 2 ports 80 & 4000 for a single SSL enabled domain?

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, https, mixed-content

I am new to SSL encryptions and need help! (Using cert bot).

I recently activated SSL on a website that runs on apache and linux on port 80. So, the current website looks like:

```
http://example.com --> https://example.com (done)
```

However, I have backend running on port 4000 and want to encrypt that as well to avoid "Mixed Content" page error:

```
http://example.com:4000 --> https://example.com:4000 (Not done yet)
```

This is exactly what I need and no work around would help. Please guide.

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Hey Vaibhav,
You can redirect a subdomain `subdomain.example.com` to point to `example.com:4000` and request a new certificate from LetsEncrypt and specify multiple subdomains when requesting a certificate. 
`certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/example/ -d www.example.com -d example.com -w /var/www/other -d other.example.net -d another.other.example.net`

Check out the official certbot documentation [here](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#webroot)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new subdomain `subdomain.example.com` and point it to `example.com:4000` and then request a new SSL certificate from LetsEncrypt and specify multiple subdomains when requesting a certificate using certbot.

```
certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/example/ -d www.example.com -d example.com -w /var/www/other -d other.example.net -d another.other.example.net
```

When you have the certificate and key, add it in your webserver config

Check out the official certbot documentation [here](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#webroot)